# How can there be instantaneous rate of change?

Tags: kinematics, time, velocity, differentiation, discrete

To find rate of change you need two instants. 
how is the rate of change calculated at a particular instant when at least two instants are needed to find it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can there be really any instantaneous velocity?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/116955/)

Answer (score 1):

That's why Newton invented the concept of "derivative".  You could ask yourself: how can a curve have a local slope, as "slope" is the rise in y value at two different x values.  The trick is to use the tangent line, which is the limiting concept of the line linking both points on the curve defining a slope.